# error: Invalid use of void expression , in a class method declaration

Tags: c++

Here's the deal. I am trying to build an EditorBuffer class (for text editing of a single line).

The class consists of two stacks of characters `(stack<char> before , stack<char> after)` where the before stack represents all the characters which are situated before the "cursor" while the after stack represents all the characters after the "cursor". In the declaration shown below i got the error `error: Invalid use of void expression` which is totally alien to me.

Here is the method declaration:

```
void EditorBuffer::moveCursorToEnd()
{
    while (!after.empty())
    {
        before.push(after.pop());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::stack::pop()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/pop/) doesn't return anything (its return type is `void`).  You probably want to do:

```
before.push(after.top());
after.pop();
```